# In Objective-C, how to initialize a really global variable that's not belong to any class?

Tags: objective-c

I have a .h file like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]

long colorPresetHex = 0xdedede; // this is OK.
UIColor *colorPreset = UIColorFromRGB (colorPresetHex); // Error
```

This .h will be called from many places that requires this 'standard'. The problem is there's an error occurred on the line `UIColor *colorPreset = UIColorFromRGB (colorPresetHex);` said "initializer element is not a compile-time constant". Now I know why this is happened. What I want to do is how to work around this issue so that I can import this header file on any project and can immediately use the `colorPreset` variable. I've tried to put the initializer on .m, but it does not work either:

```
.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]

long colorPresetHex = 0xdedede; 
UIColor *colorPreset;

.m
#import ".h"
UIColor *colorPreset = UIColorFromRGB (colorPresetHex); // error: Redefinition of 'colorPreset'
colorPreset = UIColorFromRGB (colorPresetHex); // error: Redefinition of 'colorPreset' with different type: 'int' vs 'UIColor *__strong'
```

How can I work around this? I'd like to keep the initializer on this .h or .m, because I might copy these two files to another project, and if the initializer is in different class, that might make everything messy. Thanks.

Comment: Please do not use macros and global variables. There are reasons why programmers stopped using them.

Comment: @Sulthan the only alternatives I know to avoid this global variable is just copy everything into every classes, initialise everything in every classes, even though I will never change it again throughout the app programmatically (sort of `const`). If I have to add, change, or remove a value, then I'll have to change it for every class I have, and double check to make sure that that one variable is changed in every class. That doesn't sound like something efficient for me.

Comment: Nope. The trick is to use categories (e.g. `UIColor` category) and properties on singleton objects. The usage is the same but the code quality improves greately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `extern` keyword. [Here's an exhaustive explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1433387/129889), but the short answer is to declare the variable in your header file like this:

```
extern UIColor *colorPreset;
```

Then define it in a `.m` file like this:

```
UIColor *colorPreset;
```

Then give set its value early in your program.

The `extern` means, "This variable is stored somewhere else." Without it, the compiler thinks that every `.m` file that imports your header is defining a new version of the variable with the same name, which is the "redefinition" in your error.

If you use extern, then you can define it in only one `.m` file and have no error.

Comment: Can I have a way to set the value in the .m directly for the "non compile-time constant variables"? Or do I ultimately have to set the value in the first entry point of the program (that is within the class AppDelegate in my case)?

Comment: You'll have to initialize it from the entry point. That's why it's conventional to expose computed constants like these as static methods instead of global variables. For example, [`[UIColor redColor]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIColor/redColor) as opposed to `UIColorRed`.

Comment: I think you've just unexpectedly given me the answer I'm searching for. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks to you, my code now much more cleaner using global class with static methods to return definitive values. I actually have just realised that I can just use global simple C functions to return those "non compile-time constant values", and use it to act like a variables, just like this methods. But this results in much simpler and more readable code.